# Postioning part of Image to be invisible

Tags: html, css, position, positioning

could you help to find a solution.
I have this page, and want to remove this white square.
It caused by my Image which is in absolute position and part of it is outside the container.

So my main goal - to make part of this img be outside the screen on small devices and let container to be in the center of page. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkbdT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use absolute use relative. Then second use media query. Third, if you want to cut the image use the snipping tool. You can also use object-fit command of css to cut. This might help you!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was -add to specific resolution html {
overflow-x: hidden
}

maybe will be helpfull